# python: change values in dataframe based on values of other dataframe

Tags: dataframe, rank

I am trying to change the values in one dataframe based on values of another dataframe. Is there an easy way to do that? Any help appreciated!!

1.) Dataframe Date

```
Index_column    A       B       C       D    
1               5%     12%     29%      14%
2               9%     -3%     0.5%      NaN
3               35%    -7%      3%       NaN
4               4%      8%      11%       -3%
```

2.) Rank Data

```
Index_column    A       B       C       D
1               1      2     18        3
2               1      2      19      NaN
3               3      2      35       NaN
4               2     1      110        4
```

3.) Result

```
Index_column    A       B       C       D
1               5%     12%      0%      14%  
2               9%     -3%     0%       0%
3               35%    -7%      0%       0%
4               4%      8%      0%       -3%
```

I used the following code

```
df_data.loc[(df_rank[:] >= 10)] = 0
```

But I get the following error: ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 826 to array axis with dimension 1831

Rolf

Comment: I tried the following code

Comment: Are your dataframes the same size?

Comment: hi, yes both are the same size